# How to play Music (mp3, m4a etc) from Google Drive in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api, audio-player

I want to play **Music Files** like `mp3, m4a` files from **Google Drive** in Flutter.
So far, I'm able to fetch the link of files in my google drive

#### Assets I'm using

- [assets_audio_player](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player)

The `URL` I'm getting is correct, but I don't know how would I play the music from it. Because its the `URL` to the file in Google drive not to the music file actually

- The link I am getting right now: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/19kULSF4uayHozAdyV59kGb7Fum8SJS8s`
- The link I actually want: `cea6cf6223f140ee8037d7ba382ef034_en_GoldenTemplestory by Vanshika FormateConversion - Vanshika Mehra.mp3`

*I'm not sure you will be able to access this or not, its from my organization account.*

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### So, found the solution myself :)

**Two Steps:**

After getting the `Google Drive URL`. It might look something like:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19kULSF4uayHozAdyV59kGb7Fum8SJS8s

- Get the `<FILE_ID>` from Google Drive URL

In my case the `<FILE_ID>` is `19kULSF4uayHozAdyV59kGb7Fum8SJS8s`. Its the ending portion after `d/` or sometimes there is `id=` make sure to work according to your case.

- Concatenate it with the link

[https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=`](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=%60)<FILE_ID>`

### Finally!

That's what your link will be used as `Audio.network(url)` to play the audio file from Google Drive.

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=19kULSF4uayHozAdyV59kGb7Fum8SJS8s

Comment: Do you know anything about the bandwidth google drive provide, for example, if there are 1000 listeners listening to this file from your drive, will google charge you for that?

Comment: Sorry sir I'm not sure of it, for me the users are 300-400 for now.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Please let me know if you face any trouble with this or get anything related to this from google drive.

Comment: Yes sure why not :)

Comment: @Hamza. I also want to know how much listener listen to my my file.Did you get any experience?

Comment: after couple song play, i got error TYPE_SOURCE: Response code: 403
, there is limited by google

Answer (score 0):

This is my case.

1. Package: https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio
2. Google drive share link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oXhIg5iTGwYrl9_pEPmXEJieoi_i9w9y/view?usp=sharing
3. You must convert to: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1oXhIg5iTGwYrl9_pEPmXEJieoi_i9w9y

Thanks to: https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/o1htzt/using_google_drive/

Answer (score 0):

You can't using this for free, for me, after some song i got this error

```
TYPE_SOURCE: Response code: 403
```

Usage limit exceeded, but maybe some of you had idea to solve this error? clear cache maybe?